# Is the set of diagonal matrices with positive entries open in the set of positive definite symmetric matrices?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I suspect that it's not, but would like to know a proof for why the set of diagonal matrices with positive entries is or isn't open in the set of positive definite symmetric matrices.

I am familiar with what it means to being open as in for any point in the subset there exists a small ball around that point also in that subset, but I don't know how this translates to sets of matrices.

Comment: Points in the neighborhood of a diagonal matrix include plenty of nondiagonal matrices. Your conjecture seems wrong to me.

Comment: The comment above seems to give a correct proof that the set _isn't_ open.  Note that to compute expressions for a neighborhood you could use the fact that all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, i.e. define open balls in terms of the metric induced by any norm on the space of matrices (whichever is easiest).

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be diagonal with positive diagonal entries, choose as $B$ any positive definite matrix that is not diagonal and consider $A_n := A + \frac B n$. Then each of the $A_n$ is positive definite and none of them is diagonal. So, your set is definitely not open (except for the case where the space is one-dimensional).